# How do I format specifically time in EJS?

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I am trying to format a time i got from my database. It is only a time value NOT a date value. getHours and getMinutes dont seem to work on EJS.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing EJS does is take a file with EJS templating instructions, and replace those templating instructions using the context variables you give it as part of a `render()` call.

You don't "format time in EJS": it only does one thing, and your job is to make sure it has all the data ready for templating. So: turn your timestamp into a date *on the JS side*, then put that date in the context object for EJS, then reference that value in your EJS.